# Updating Binary files

Tags: c++, binary

I have a binary file `employee.dat`

Record Structure:

```
struct employee{
    int employee_no;
    char surname[20],forename[20];
    char sex;
    float salary,bonus;
};
```

I want to write a program to update (upon entry of an employee number) the employees salary where the new salary will be int the range of 7,500-250,000.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: It would be best to show the part of your code that writes the file. And ask questions about that. We are not here to do your homework if that is the question.

Comment: What do you tried out? What is the question? Don't ask to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

First, write the following:

```
#include <iostream> // for console I/O
#include <fstream>  // for reading binary files.
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This should be your foundation.  Get it working.

If the data file exists, you should try something simple, like printing the employee names:

```
int main(void)
{
   employee e;
   std::ifstream  data_file(/* insert filename here */, ios::binary);
   if (!data_file)
   {
     std::cerr << "Error opening data file.\n";
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   // Read one record.
   data_file.read((char *) &e, sizeof(e));
   cout << "Read employee record for: "
        << e.forename
        << " "
        << e.surname
        << "\n";
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

From here, you can take several development paths:
1) Read one record at a time, and test the employee ID or name.
2) Read in a block or group of employees into a buffer, then search the buffer.

Look up some methods:  `seekg`, `seekp`, opening file fore read and write, `write`.

If this wasn't specific, please post a more detailed question with the issues you are having with your attempt.